# Pros & cons of redirecting all http to https

Tags: azure, redirect, https

A question in two parts, on redirecting http to https

We have just implemented an Azure web site with SSL. Some of the pages have a redirect from http to https in Page_Load, using:

```
        if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection) {
            string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, false);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

First part - is there any downside to redirecting *all* pages to https?

Second part - if not, then is the above code the best way to do it, or should we use URL rewrite like this:

```
  <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
  </rule>
```

All suggestions welcome.

Regards

Comment: Can the person who down voted let me know why? I'd like to improve my use of SO.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you should redirect all http requests to https. You should learn and use HSTS too.

There is no downside to do so, and it is far more secure and less error prone than maintaining mixed http/https entries points.

For the redirect method, as long as it is a 301 (permanent) redirect, use the easiest to maintain/implement.